# Is it possible in datepicker to show selected year only and not range?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). In this datepicker, now I want to show only selected year which may not be in range. E.g. I want to show calendar of year 2015, 1017 and not 2016 or beyond 2017. Is it possible?

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Note that you're using the [eyecon fork](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) of bootstrap-datepicker which was abandoned in March 2013, but it would be better to use the [eternicode fork](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) which is actively maintained and has more features.

Answer (score 0):

I know you could grey them out by filtering using beforeShowDay. As for the max year requirement, just throw in a maxDate as well.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  return [(date < ys || date > ye), ''];
},
```

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fkzufoxp/

Comment: Can it be done for years. I mean when you click on year and get all the years, in that place.